# Linked List C++. insertion, deletion, search

Tags: c++, search, linked-list

Any advice or guidance would be very great...

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string.h>


  using namespace std;

 struct Book { 
char title[1024];       // Book name
int id;                 // Book id or ISBN number
float price;            // Book price
struct Book* next;
  } *COLLECTION = NULL;

//-- Forward Declaration --// 
void menu(); 
void branching(char option);
void insertion();
void printall();
struct Book* search(); 
void deletion();
void quit(struct Book* HEAD);


 int main()
 {
char ch; 

cout << "\n\nWelcome to CSE240: Bookstore\n";

do {
     menu();

     ch = tolower(getchar()); // read a char, convert to lower case
     cin.ignore();

     branching(ch);
} while (ch != 'q');

return 0; 
}

 void menu()
    {
cout << "\nMenu Options\n";
cout << "------------------------------------------------------\n";
cout << "i: Insert a book\n";
cout << "d: Delete a book\n";
cout << "s: Search a book\n";
cout << "p: Review your list\n"; 
cout << "q: Quit\n";
cout << "\n\nPlease enter a choice (i, d, s, p, or q) ---> "; 
 }

  void branching(char option)
 {
switch(option)
{
    case 'i':
        insertion();
    break;

    case 'd':
        deletion();
    break;

    case 's':
        search();
    break;

    case 'p':
        printall();
    break;

    case 'q':
        quit(COLLECTION);
        COLLECTION = NULL;
    break;

    default:
        cout << "\nError: Invalid Input.  Please try again..."; 
    break;
}
 }


  void insertion()
  {
// add code to insert a new book into the COLLECTION linked list.   
// HINT: You can insert a new book at the beginning of the linked list


 }

  struct Book* search() 
 {    
// add code to search for an existing book in the COLLECTION linked-list
// HINT: If no book matches the tile return a error messag



return NULL;
 }

 void deletion()
 {
// add code to the deletion method. You must call "delete" to remove the object    from the heap.
  }

  void printall()
  {
// Add code to print the book collection.  (HINT: You will need to use a loop.)

  }

  void quit(struct Book* HEAD)
  {
// Add code to delete the objects/books from the lniked-list.
// HINT: Refer to the slides in the homework assignment


   }
```

Comment: What is the problem?  What do you expect your program to do?  What does it actually do?

Comment: When learning about lists (and other data structures) I find that a piece of paper where you can draw the current state of the list, the state that you want the list to be in after the operation and seeing the updates that need to be applied usually helps. Other than that, if you have been working on this for a couple of hours, you should have at least some rough approximation of some of the functions that you can show, explain what you intended on doing...

Comment: Right now the biggest problem is see is no attempt at actually *implementing* the skeleton of functions you've provided.

Comment: It should be able to insert a new node into the linked list, as well as have the ability to search, and delete nodes

Comment: @user2044651: And what have you tried?

Comment: @ David, yeah I do have a rough idea of what methods to use, but I failed when implementing. For insert: I tried malloc, cin and cout, p->title. for the delete: I'm trying it to do it recursively. and Search: I tried a loop.

Comment: Delete all the code and use `std::list` instead.  There are other options too:  `std::map`, `std::set`, `std::deque`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a clue for `insertion()` - assuming you have a book you want to insert

```
void insertion(Book* newBook)
{
  // The new book will be inserted at the beginning of the linked list,
  // with the original list following on from it
  newBook->next = COLLECTION;

  // The new beginning of the collection should be the new book
  COLLECTION = newBook;
}
```

And for `search()` - assuming you are searching for a book with a particular ID

```
Book* search(int id) 
{
  Book* current = COLLECTION;

  while(current != NULL)
  {
    if(current->id == id)
    {
      // Found it
      return current;
    }

    // Try the next book in the list
    current = current->next;
  }

  // Reached the end, but still could not find the book you are looking for
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I'd use `while(current != NULL)` instead of the first if, and `return current` at the end. It is the same effect, but more cleaner, IMHO.

Comment: Very true! Thanks Matheus. I edited my solution to reflect your suggestion.